# Hide playback as default? Set spacebar to end command? Delete key

Tags: interface

I'm new to blender. A couple Questions. I'm pretty certain I will not be creating animation in the near future. How can I get it to not show the playback area at the bottom of the screen and make that the default? Also, can I set the space-bar to something other than animation playback? Preferably esc/end command like in my other software?
Can I remap keys. E.g. Set "delete" key to delete objects.

Comment: Hi @NicholasScott, welcome to [blender.se] on Stack Exchange. Questions should show some degree of research before being posted here.  I feel that these points could have been resolved with some exploration of the interface and a bit of googling.  I'm not going to down-vote it but please be aware that those who offer their time for free expect the asker to at least try before-hand.

Answer (score 0):

for default startup scene you can setup the layout as you like and than go to **File --> Defaults --> Save startup File**.

[image]

for the keymap, you can go to **Edit --> Preferences --> Keymap** and change stuff there.

[image]

Comment: While this addresses both issues, the order should be reversed otherwise the OP may no know to save startup after modifying settings.